# Spring cloud config environment variable interpolation

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

I'm using `spring-cloud-config` in my **Spring Boot** project and I don't understand how to interpolate environment variables.

For example I have `MYSQL_PASSWORD` variable set in the `config server` (as environment variable) and I want to get it from other clients, without redefining the variable inside all of them. This is my config:

**service.yml (in config-server)**

```
spring:
  datasource:
     url: jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/${MYSQL_DATABASE}?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
     username: ${MYSQL_USER}
     password: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
```

**bootstrap.yml (into the client)**

```
spring:
  application:
     name: event-service
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: http://config-service:8888
      fail-fast: true
```

If I start my services with this configuration, placeholder `${MYSQL_***}` is not interpolated and I cannot connect to the database obviously.

What I have to do to make it work is to define environment variables like `MYSQL_***` also in the client.

This is weird for me as I want config-server to be the central repository for everything. Do you have any advice?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try to replace ${MYSQL_USER} and ${MYSQL_PASSWORD} with ${mysql.user} and ${mysql.password} - that way you'll be relying on Spring Boot's default property replacement.

Although I'm not sure that configuration server supports what you're trying to use, I've never tried a similar use case, please write back with a solution if the approach I suggested didn't work :)